Utilize react component over URLs dyanamically
I have a React component say TEST.TSX , I have compiled the .tsx file to .js and uploaded it to GitHub, so that I can server it over JsDelivr. Can I use the CDN in another react app to utilize the Test component?
I have tried module-federation, but it requires me to host the remote-app/component containing the (Test component), I cannot use hosting as it is an additional cost.
I have tried bundling the NextJS app (having component Test) and utilizing it using the script generated but failed to use it.
I have tried compiling TEST.tsx to .js file and then utilizing it from CDN, but failed to do so, while I was able to use the component using import when I kept the script in a local folder.
I think it's not possible, as the react components /react must be compiled before running. Please let me know if you guys have any ideas.
I cannot use Iframes as well as it requires hosting.
Basically, just let me know if there are any ways to utilize react components (.TSX/.JSX/.TS/.JS) Files directly from hosted drive locations. (CDNs)
My webpack.config.js file :
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './app/export-component.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'exports.js',
    library: 'MyLibrary', // Set a name for the library
    libraryTarget: 'umd', // Set the module type (Universal Module Definition)
    globalObject: 'this', // To support both browser and Node.js environments
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
        use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['solid'],
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
         ],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
};



My exportComponent.js
// export-components.js
import DemoClientComponent from './components/DemoClientComponent';
import PayButton from './components/PayButton';
// Option 1: Export individual components
export { DemoClientComponent ,PayButton};

// Option 2: Export as an object (if applicable)
export default function ExportComponents() {
    DemoClientComponent,
    PayButton
};



My DemoClientComponents.tsx File in  (./app/components) :
import React from 'react';

const DemoClientComponent = () => (
  <>
  
    <h1>Hello from Braintree</h1>
  </>
);

export default DemoClientComponent;



I have uploaded the resulted export.js https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pradeep-yadav-amla/DemoComponent@1.0.5/export.js to,and configured other app's layout.tsx to use the script.
Other app's code :
"use client"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const RemoteFetch = () => {
  const [innerHtml, setInnerhtml] = useState(); 
  useEffect(() => {
    const innerHtml = window.MyLibrary.DemoClientComponent();
    setInnerhtml(innerHtml)
  }, []);

return (
  <>
  {innerHtml && innerHtml.outerHTML && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html : innerHtml.outerHTML}}>

  </div>}
  </>
);};



export default RemoteFetch;



How can I do the same for using components using typescript functions/react-hooks ?

Could you please specify how exactly did you try to add component from CDN? Did you try to do it via html script tag, dynamic import or something else?

Yes I added it as an script , and then tried to render the component from it , although couldn't achieve it

And locally you do the same with the script located on your machine? Do you mind providing some code, showing, how you do it?

Added the code @VladyslavShlianin

Also is it even possible as I am new to nextjs/React

I see what you're trying to do. If your goal is to lazy load component, you can use React lazy import with Suspense. If you want to host component on separate environment, things would be a bit more complicated. In that case you can load your component via HTML tag, but that would require building it as a separate React application and mounting it in some specific node within your application

In other words, you can't really just host a separate component bundle, import it with script and use as usual. It seems like you have a global MyLibrary variable and populate it within your component hosted on CDN. So, not a straightforward way either. If you don't mind telling why exactly are you trying to host component separately, I would help to find an optimal solution for your case

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
